# How can I download IIS express by command?

Tags: windows, nuget

1. Can I use nuget tool getting latest version of IIS express? How if can?
2. If nuget cannot do that, is there any way else that I can complete this task in one command line? Windows7

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are searching for something like this:

```
Install-WindowsFeature -Name Web-Server -IncludeAllSubFeature -IncludeManagementTools -ComputerName Server1 -Credential contoso.com\johnj99
```

See [Install-WindowsFeature](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us//library/jj205467(v=wps.630).aspx) for more details.